# How to dynamically and conditionally assign dictionary values?

Tags: python, dictionary, dynamic

I am trying to assign values to a dictionary but I will not know what the values are or even if they exist ahead of time. I initialize my dictionary with None values or I assign it to be the value from an input dictionary. The problem is the input dictionary may not have values for certain keys, or may not even have the keys in the first place.

Other than checking for each and every key if it exists and then assigning it if it does exist, is there a way I can just set up the dictionary key values to have a default value of None and if there is a key: value in the input dictionary to assign the key in the output dictionary to that value instead?

As an example I have some of the values assigned to values from the input dict and some just assigned to None.

What I'd like to do is something like `{'<node>': if exists(node['id']: node['id] else: None}`

But this obviously won't work.

```
def nvalues(node):

nrowtemp = {'<node>': node['id'], '<namespace>': node['namespace'], '<title>': node['<title>'], '<category>': None, '<submittable>': None, '<description>': None, '<link_name>': None, '<additionalProperties>' : None, '<contraints>': None, '<program>': None, '<project>': None, '<backref>': None, '<label>': None, '<target>': None, '<multiplicity>': None, '<link_required>': None, '<link_group_required>': None, '<group_exclusive>': None}`
```

Comment: Look at defaultdict https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict

Answer (score 0):

See below

```
nodes = [{'id':12,'namespace':'ns1'},{'id':17},{'not_id':12,'namespace':'ns2'}]
keys = ['id','namespace']
new_nodes = []
for node in nodes:
  new_nodes.append({k:node.get(k) for k in keys})
print(new_nodes)
```

output

```
[{'id': 12, 'namespace': 'ns1'}, {'id': 17, 'namespace': None}, {'id': None, 'namespace': 'ns2'}]
```